Is it possible for the BashOperator to access files saved in a directory by a PythonOperator?
I'm currently working on a project where I need to grep some lines out of a selection of very large text files. The text files are in a gcs bucket with thousands of other files.  They need to be compared against a list of filenames so that only a subsection is transformed.
I was thinking about using the python operator to use a python function to check the filenames and save them to a local directory if the filename is in the reference list.  Following this I need to process the text files with some bash commands (just grepping out the lines I need and doing some cleanup with sed).
My questions is: will the BashOperator be able to access the directory that is created and populated by the PythonOperator?

Python has functions to match regular expressions, why wouldn't you do everything in Python?

it seemed easier to me to run a one line sed command than to implement that functionality in python.
Basically I have some files that are 10s of thousands of lines, but I only care about a few lines within the files.  So my thought was to just use sed oneliner to clean up all the files at once and then send them back to a gcs bucker.

It depends on what your Airflow deployment looks like.  Is your Airflow deployed on Kubernetes?  Then the file system gets set on fire after each task completes.  Pods are ephemeral or short lived.  So there's nothing to access in the later task.
If you're running everything on a single EC2, then yes it might be feasible.  But it's an antipattern in my opinion and according to Airflow's docs.  The cross-task communication mechanism in Airflow is Xcoms.
Airflow's example xcoms DAG should be helpful for getting started with the feature.

You're right it is an anti pattern.  I wound up just implementing a pure python solution using the regex library.
